# Suggested edits attributed to you but not made by you

Tags: discussion

Sorry if this has been asked before but I could not find it.  On some of my suggested edits, when I check the pending edit status - some changes have been attributed to me which I did not make

For example [See edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/17252617)

I did not change

> combine joins and includes together

to

> make it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The post was edited by someone else after you started editing it, so when you submitted your edit you ended up submitting a new revision that doesn't contain those changes, which effectively results in you proposing an edit that has reversed those changes.